# Gutenberg: Is there a way to know if current block is inside InnerBlocks?

Tags: filters, block-editor

So I am using nested blocks in Wordpress Gutenberg. I am applying a wrapper on my elements that apply a bootstrap container class.
Obviously I'd only want that on the outermost blocks, not on the ones inside a nested block.

Is there a way to know if the current block is inside a `InnerBlocks` Definiton of a parent block? 
I am currently applying the wrapper inside the `blocks.getSaveElement` Filter.

Is there a better way to do this?

For context:
In previous gutenberg versions there used to be the layout attribute to achieve that, but it has since been removed. I am using Version 3.9.0.

This is a shortened version of my wrapper function:

```
    namespace.saveElement = ( element, blockType, attributes ) => {
        const hasBootstrapWrapper = hasBlockSupport( blockType.name, 'bootstrapWrapper' );

        if (hasBlockSupport( blockType.name, 'anchor' )) {
            element.props.id = attributes.anchor;
        }
        if (hasBootstrapWrapper) {

            // HERE I NEED TO CHECK IF THE CURRENT ELEMENT IS INSIDE A INNERBLOCKS ELEMENT AND THEN APPLY DIFFERENT WRAPPER

            var setWrapperInnerClass = wrapperInnerClass;
            var setWrapperClass = wrapperClass;
            if (attributes.containerSize) {
                setWrapperInnerClass = wrapperInnerClass + ' ' + attributes.containerSize;
            }
            if (attributes.wrapperType) {
                setWrapperClass = wrapperClass + ' ' + attributes.wrapperType;
            }

            const setWrapperAnchor = (attributes.wrapperAnchor) ? attributes.wrapperAnchor : false;

            return (
                newEl('div', { key: wrapperClass, className: setWrapperClass, id: setWrapperAnchor},
                    newEl('div', { key: wrapperInnerClass, className: setWrapperInnerClass},
                        element
                    )
                )
            );
        } else {
            return element;
        }
    };

wp.hooks.addFilter('blocks.getSaveElement', 'namespace/gutenberg', namespace.saveElement);
```

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 11):

`getBlockParents` will work accurately. You can use `getBlockParents` with the `clientId` of the block, `getBlockParents` will return the all parent blocks id if the current block is under any Blocks. It will return blank if current block is not under any Block

here is a method that you can use:

```
const innerBlock = "namespace/block-name";
const parentBlocks = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockParents(props.clientId); 
const parentAttributes = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlocksByClientId(parentBlocks);

var is_under_inner = false;
for (i = 0; i < parentAttributes.length; i++) {
    if ( parentAttributes[i].name == innerBlock ) {
        is_under_inner = true;
    }
}

//console.log(is_under_inner);
```

Answer (score 9):

you can call `getBlockHierarchyRootClientId` with the clientId of the block, `getBlockHierarchyRootClientId` will return the parent block id if the current block is inside innerBlocks and will return the same id if it's root

you can call it like this

```
wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getBlockHierarchyRootClientId( clientId );
```

additionally, you can define a helper function that you can use in your code

```
const blockHasParent = ( clientId ) => clientId !== wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getBlockHierarchyRootClientId( clientId );

if ( blockHasParent( yourClientId ) { 
    ....
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that at the time `blocks.getSaveElement` runs no `clientId` has been assigned yet so it looks like it is not possible from inside the filter. Maybe a solution could be achieved trying a work around in some other way.

Comment: you can use [`editor.blockListBlock`](https://github.com/wordpress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters.md#editorblocklistblock) to run a check inside the block and assign a class or something